# How to show today date selected in ngx-bootstrap when click on date picker textbox to open a date picker

Tags: html, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I want to select today date in ngx-bootstrap date picker when it is open.

Answer (score 4):

Appart from binding. If you simply want to highligh todays date, based on [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#today-class) you can define a custom css class:

```
.custom-today-class{ background-color:blue; }
```

Then specify it in the `bsConfig` property:

```
 <input type="text"  bsDatepicker  [bsConfig]="{ customTodayClass:'custom-today-class' }"  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your `component.ts`, you can do something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'YOUR_FILE',
  templateUrl: './YOUR_FILE.html'
})
export class DemoDatePickerPopupComponent {

  bsValue: Date = new Date();
}
```

And in your `HTML`, you can do

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           #dp="bsDatepicker"
           bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-3 form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="dp.toggle()">Date Picker</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have added bsValue: Date = new Date(); in component and [(bsValue)]="bsValue" in html input field but it doesn't show the selected date.

Comment: Try restarting the server.

Comment: But when i changed [(bsValue)] with [(ngModel)] then it show selected date and today date on input field, but i dont want date on input field